# Advanced Python 3 list for loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

**Note this is a simplified exampe** is it possible to do something like

```
l=[[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],["x","y","z"]
```

then have a for loop that itterates through all of the first items in each list then all the second, then all the 3rd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `zip(...)` function.

```
>>> for elem in zip(*l):
        for a in elem:
            print(a)


1
a
x
2
b
y
3
c
z
```

**Also**, you could use `zip_longest(...)` (`izip_longest` for Py2x) for lists of uneven length.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> l=[[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],["x","y"]]
>>> for elem in zip_longest(*l, fillvalue='Empty'):
        print(elem)


(1, 'a', 'x')
(2, 'b', 'y')
(3, 'c', 'Empty')
```

Comment: use unpack not a second for loop!

Comment: That depends on how many values there are in the sequence. The OP says it's a simplified example, so I made a generic case.

Comment: Thanks for showing the in even length. That will be useful later on. @PeterVaro What are the pros/cons of unpack?